# Java Arrays.sort() Taking a Long Time

Tags: java, sorting

I am using Java's `Arrays.sort()` function to sort a list of files by their last modified time. The sort for 245 files is taking around 5 seconds. This seems too long to me. I feel it shouldn't take more than 0.5 seconds. Is that a good assumption? What am I doing wrong? OR does this sound normal?

```
public static class LastModifiedComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return (int)(f1.lastModified() - f2.lastModified());
    }       
}

File folder = new File( "C:\\Whatever\\" );
File[] filesInFolder = folder.listFiles();
logger.debug("Starting File Sort");
Arrays.sort(filesInFolder, new LastModifiedComparator());
logger.debug("Done File Sort");
```

Output in Log

```
2012-08-10 14:24:20,333 DEBUG http-8080-4 <ClassName>:73 - Starting File Sort
2012-08-10 14:24:25,915 DEBUG http-8080-4 <ClassName>:75 - Done File Sort
```

Comment: If the files are unique (all have different equals methods) it would be interesting to use a TreeSet and see what happens. You may have to wrap the file in another class implementing comparator. 5 seconds does seem a long time though!

Comment: How many files are there in the folder?

Comment: Also have you tried it as a collection and using a ArrayList and Collections.sort(). Is that any different?

Comment: You don't tell us how large this array is that you're sorting.  It could easily be that the array is *very* large.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to improve your `Comparator` logic. You need to **cache** the `lastModified()` values because the implementation of that method is quite slow. I suggest wrapping the `File` instances into a *comparable* object of your making that will cache the value:

```
public class FileLmWrapper implements Comparable<FileLmWrapper> {
  public final File f;
  public final long lastModified;
  public FileLmWrapper(File f) { 
    this.f = f; 
    lastModified = f.lastModified();
  }
  public int compareTo(FileLmWrapper other) {
    return Long.compare(this.lastModified, other.lastModified);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the wrapper worked like a charm! The sort is in the order of milliseconds now. However, the whole operation still takes around 1 second. I'm guessing constructing those 245 `FileLmWrapper` objects takes time. Maybe I should try putting the times in a HashMap instead of using a wrapper!

Comment: @Danish 245 object allocations is going to take virtually no time. If you look at my post below, I actually predicted that it would take you about 1 second by extrapolating from how long each call to `lastModified()` takes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it the `lastModified()` that will define the lower limit on the run-time of this operation.

Comment: @Danish I still don't know why it takes a second, though. 245 calls to `lastModified()` took about 5.5 milliseconds on my not-extremely-powerful laptop.

Comment: @yshavit Probably because the folder is on a network drive. That's one piece of information I missed to mention in my question.

Comment: Your compareTo will produce the wrong value, because of overflow, for files with very different modification times.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Do you? The `lastModified()` method teturns a value in milliseconds. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` milliseconds is less than a month.

Comment: The significance is that the `compareTo` method returns an `int`. Subtracting one `long` from another then casting to an `int` was the problem.

Comment: @Raedwald Then there were *two* problems :) In any case, the change fixes both.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Please how is this now implemented? `Arrays.sort(files, new FileLmWrapper());` wants a File parameter, but I don't know what to pass into it. Thank you.

Comment: @oracle I wonder how your code even compiles because that's how you'd use a `Comparator` and this is an implementation of `Comparable`. You're supposed to wrap every file into `FileLmWrapper`, so you have a `List<FileLmWrapper>`, and you sort that. I think with the Streams APi this can be done in three simple steps.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Apologies. I am just really confused. Ok assuming I have `File[] filesInFolder = folder.listFiles();` , please show me an example of how to sort the file array using your class above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

`File.lastModified` has to go to the OS to query when the file was last modified -- it's not cached. You're doing that twice per comparison, and [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) uses a [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) -- `O(n log n)`. Plugging in 245 for `n`, That's about 580 comparisons, or 1100 calls to the OS to get the last modified time. That means you can get about 230 last-modified calls per second. That seems maybe a bit slow, but certainly more plausible than an in-JVM comparison taking that long

As Marko Topolnik abd NgSan points out above, the fix would be to first cache the last-modified times for all the Files. I would do it by creating a new class object that combines the File and that time, and then sort those objects. That way you'll have only 245 calls to `File.lastModified`, and the sort should take about 1/5th the time.

Comment: Here you assume that all of `O(n log n)` stems from comparisons. Is it really so? There's also copying and merging involved.

Comment: I think the bulk of it is, yes. I whipped up a quick little test that shows it: http://pastebin.com/Z7DNtiF1 (*warning:* will spam your working directory with a ton of empty files!)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And just to round it out: When I ran that program on my machine, the ints had 1721 comparisons and took 2.1 ms. The files had 244 comparisons (they all have the same lastModified time since they get created so quickly, so the sort is just `O(n)`) and still took 5.5 ms. If the files were randomly ordered by modification date, it would have taken about 39.0 ms (still much quicker than OP's! I don't know what's wrong with his disk).

Comment: Yeah, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it sounds like it's doing disk I/O each time you read the Modified Time- thus the slowness. It might be faster to simply get the modified times in an object along with the File object, and *then* sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your compare operation

```
@Override
public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
    return (int)(f1.lastModified() - f2.lastModified());
}
```

isn't just a getter but issues a call to get the information from file system so the high response time of sort is moreover due to the performance of `lastModified()` than `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

The sort implemented in java in <strike>modified Quick Sort</strike> tuned Merge Sort which will have average running time complexity of O(nlogn). 
 So we need to concentrate on your File operations like getting lastModifiedTime. Are you sure those files are local files or shared drive which takes the network latency?

Comment: Actually it's merge sort, which does much less comparison than quick sort, at the expense of more memory.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, You are right. Actually only for primitive types its doing tuned quick sort but in case of objects, merge sort is implemented.